# How do I change suffix (enter key to other key like ctrl+1) in barcode scanner?

Tags: javascript

i want to differentiate whether user enter the value from key board or barcode scanner. onKeyPress event i have one javascript function By default barcode scanner input returning as enter key. is it possible to change suffix value?

```
 function getBarCodeDtls(evnt, val){
       document.forms(0).isScaned.value="N";
      if(val!="" && evnt.keyCode==13){
          document.forms(0).isScaned.value="Y";
          document.forms(0).scannedValue.value=val;
        }

        if(document.forms(0).scannedValue.value != val){
            document.forms(0).isScaned.value="N";
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <form>
    <input type="textbox" name="txtBarcodeReader" value="" onKeyPress="return getBarCodeDtls(event, this.value);" />
    <input type ="textbox" name="isScaned" value ="" />
    <input type ="textbox" name="scannedValue" value ="" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read the official documentation of your barcode scanner - there you will find the exact barcode that you need to scan in order to change the prefix or suffix or remove them. If you have more than 1 barcode scanners - you will have to do this operation for each of them.